# Trying to get a date picker to work in asp.net C# page with Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up a form in asp.net with Bootstrap and include a date/calendar picker for an input field.   But , I'm having no luck, as it just displays an input field.  It isn't clickable, and no calendar icon appears to the right of the input box.  Does anything jump out at you as wrong or what I"m forgetting to do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Datatables.net CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.3/b-1.5.6/b-colvis-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/b-print-1.5.6/cr-1.5.0/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/kt-2.5.0/r-2.2.2/rg-1.1.0/rr-1.2.4/sc-2.0.0/sl-1.3.0/datatables.min.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa8bd4cc4b.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/af-2.3.3/b-1.5.6/b-colvis-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/b-print-1.5.6/cr-1.5.0/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/kt-2.5.0/r-2.2.2/rg-1.1.0/rr-1.2.4/sc-2.0.0/sl-1.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script>
     $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    });
    $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like you want to use *[bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)* but forgot to include necessary javascript and css files?

*bootstrap* doesn't come with datepicker library.

After referencing them everything works fine:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker" />
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/gsuntkyr/4/

[image]

Comment: Adding the cdn & css solved my problem.  I originally misunderstood and thought bootstrap came with a datepicker library.  Thank you.